# Extending a Singleton Class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I'm trying to Extend and override a method in a Singleton Class in TypeScript, here's the code for the **Singleton Class:**

```
class Singleton {
    protected static _instance: Singleton;

    protected constructor() { }

    public static get instance() {
        if (Singleton._instance === undefined) {
            Singleton._instance = new Singleton();
        }

        return Singleton._instance;
    }

    public doWork() {
        console.log('doing work in singleton...');
    }
}
```

**ExtendedSingleton Class:**

```
class ExtendedSingleton extends Singleton {
    protected static _instance: ExtendedSingleton;

    protected constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public static get instance() {
        console.log('Creating Extended Singleton');
        if (ExtendedSingleton._instance === undefined) {
            ExtendedSingleton._instance = new ExtendedSingleton();
        }

        return ExtendedSingleton._instance;
    }

    public doWork() {
        console.log('doing work in extended singleton...');
    }
}
```

Finally the code that runs both classes:

```
Singleton.instance.doWork();
ExtendedSingleton.instance.doWork();
```

The problem is that both logs **'doing work in singleton...'**, and when I swap the lines the problem is fixed.
I don't know why this behavior happens (I think it's mostly something I'm not aware of on how javascript's inheritance works), or if there's a better solution to my problem.

**Note:** I fixed the problem by using an interface and implementing it in both classes, but this won't be efficient in a large class where I need to override a method or two only.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Singleton` will be the prototype of `ExtendedSingleton`, whenever you access any static properties on `ExtendedSingleton`, it will check `Singleton` first for that property.

This means if `_instance` is set on `Singleton` first, then `ExtendedSingleton._instance` will return that value. It works in the other order because if `ExtendedSingleton` doesn't have an `_instance` field it gets its own, before `Singleton` gets one.

If you make `_instance` private instead of protected (since each class should have its own anyways), Typescript notices this problem and gives you an error.

One way to fix this problem would be to rename `_instance` in one or both of the classes, to make sure they both get their own field.

Comment: Changing the names fixes the problem, also forcing a value in the ExtendedSingleton _instance fixed it (initializing it with undefined or null).
If there's another solution to this please let me know, thanks.